Tkinter with thread problems(packing widget using for loop gives error)
I tried 2 way of making a tkinter window in a sub thread, one didnt work.
I am making some python code that can send files to a server using socket. And tkinter is my way to do the user interface. So, in the notification window (i want to use this instead notify of other libs since i want to customize the texts), I put Labels object each representing sending status of a file. I did it by putting them in a list. But 2 way of .pack() the Label give me different results.
By the way, the notification is run in a sub thread
Way 1: I pack it right away append them to list
`
class notify_window:
app: Tk
main = []
file: tuple
title_form = "Thông báo(TẮT SAU: {}s)"
def __init__(self, text_color, file_path) -> None:
    global app
    global FILE_LIMIT
    global FILE_LIMIT_MB
    self.app = Tk()
    self.app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.advanced_destroy)
    self.file = file_path
    for x,y in text_color:
        text: str
        color: str
        if y == 1:
            text = "ĐÃ GỬI THÀNH CÔNG " + self.file[x] +  "\n"
        elif y == 2:
            text = "KHÔNG TÌM THẤY FILE" +  self.file[x] +  "\n"
        elif y == 3:
            text = "FILE QUÁ NẶNG(TỐI ĐA: {} MB ) ".format(FILE_LIMIT_MB) + self.file[x] + "\n"
        if y == 1:
            color = "green"
        else:
            color = "red"
        append_label = Label(self.app, text= text, fg = color)
        if y != 1:
            self.main.insert(0, append_label)
        else:
            self.main.append(append_label)
        self.main[len(self.main) -1 ].pack()
    # for x in self.main:
    #     x.pack()

`
Way 2: I pack it in a for loop after append all of them to it
`
class notify_window:
app: Tk
main = []
file: tuple
title_form = "Thông báo(TẮT SAU: {}s)"
def __init__(self, text_color, file_path) -> None:
    global app
    global FILE_LIMIT
    global FILE_LIMIT_MB
    self.app = Tk()
    self.app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.advanced_destroy)
    self.file = file_path
    for x,y in text_color:
        text: str
        color: str
        if y == 1:
            text = "ĐÃ GỬI THÀNH CÔNG " + self.file[x] +  "\n"
        elif y == 2:
            text = "KHÔNG TÌM THẤY FILE" +  self.file[x] +  "\n"
        elif y == 3:
            text = "FILE QUÁ NẶNG(TỐI ĐA: {} MB ) ".format(FILE_LIMIT_MB) + self.file[x] + "\n"
        if y == 1:
            color = "green"
        else:
            color = "red"
        append_label = Label(self.app, text= text, fg = color)
        if y != 1:
            self.main.insert(0, append_label)
        else:
            self.main.append(append_label)
        # self.main[len(self.main) -1 ].pack()
    for x in self.main:
        x.pack()

`
The second way get me the "not in main thread" everytime i create the notify_window object the second time. I thought about it doenst work with multiple windows running like that, but it just gets error everytime i called the notify window the second time(in the first way it's possible to spam the window)
Here is my piece of code to run the sub thread:
#make a notify notify_board_thread = Thread(target= lambda: notify_window_innit(self.submitting_rs, self.file) ) notify_board_thread.start()
The above code runs in the main thread
